# A programatically controlled java web browser with GUI

Tags: java, facebook

I am looking for a programmatically controlled browser such as WebKit for Java.

I need to be able to launch the browser in a very minimal window from my program and point it to a certain URL.  I then need to be able to retrieve and URL that the user is redirected to.

Thanks,
Luke Cycon

(And if it helps, I am trying to authenticate with Facebook Connect, that is the end goal)

Needs to be cross platform (Written in java or the likes). WebKit for SWT is windows only at this point

Answer (score 0):

what about Qt Jambis -webkit component(note qt jambi is not an official qt binding for newer qt libraries and I'm not sure of the status of community support).

Answer (score 0):

SWT Browser widget may help you.  http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html (look at 'getUrl' method). It uses native platform rendering engine(Internet Explorer on Windows, Mozilla on Linux, Safari on the Mac). Check this tutorial http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html

Comment: Assuming this can handle links and some basic JavaScript, I think it will work.  I will try tonight and let you all know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selenium , a Mozilla plugin. http://http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

You can record any action you want into a jUnit test and then use xpath to query the response you get from the browser.

When you run the unit test it will fire open a browser window. You can work with the response in your java code.